# SQL Server Transform Imported Data Using Lookup

Tags: sql, csv, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

I am (theoretically) importing data into a SQL server database from CSV Files as follows:

**Accounts.csv:**

```
AccountID,AccountHolder,Balance
ABC-1234,Person A,100000.50
CDE-4567,Person B,30.75
FGH-8910,Person C,25.00
```

**Transactions.csv**

```
FromAccount,ToAccount,TransferAmount
FGH-8910,FGH-8910,25
ABC-456,FGH-8910,28
FGH-8910,CDE-4567,60
```

Lets say I am integrating this data into my existing tables (`Account` and `Trans`) which have the same structure as above but I have a different account numbering system (My `Account` table's `AccountID` column is `INT IDENTITY(1,1)`)

I can use SQL Server Import and Export wizard to import Accounts.csv into the Accounts table and exclude the AccountID column and the three accounts would get imported into the `Account` table and the AccountID would be assigned by the identity column.

However, When I come to import transactions.csv, I have the old account numbers.

How can I then import Transactions.csv and replace the accountID's with the new AccountIDs assigned by the identity column?

I suspect this can be done in SSIS but I am wondering if there is a way using `OPENQUERY` / `BULK IMPORT` also?

Comment: Is it safe to assume there will also be a FK on the Transaction table for the Account?

Comment: @RossBush on the database we are importing into, yes (on both the FromAccount and ToAccount columns

Comment: You can't match to the new id's using bulk import the way you describe.

Comment: Is SSIS my only option?

Comment: It depends, you are going to have to post process the data at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Process Accounts.csv ids first, add either a new id column to the file, or generate a new file with the new account ids.

Then pre-process the transactions file by replacing the old account ids with the new account ids.

Finally, process the new transaction file.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into a staging table dbo.Account_Staging (without the IDENTITY column) from the CSV file

Edit / clean up / manipulate your imported data

Copy the data across to the real table with a T-SQL statement like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Account (AccountHolder,Balance)      
SELECT AccountHolder,Balance FROM dbo.Account_Staging
```

Comment: How do I create the lookup as to which "old" account number joins with each "new" account number?

Comment: Also load Transactions into a staging table dbo.Transactions_Staging, then a cursor that updates/joins the id for both tables

Comment: OK, so this will give me the accounts with no account number and the transactions with the old account numbers?

Comment: In Staging tables you have old account number, before you insert to the main table you need cursor which updates/joins tables